# Calling REST WS with different parameters

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a basic doubt while calling a REST WS from the ajax frontend. I am calling the WS from ajax as:

```
url: self.GET_GOAL_VIEW_URL + '?userEmail=' + eMail,
```

or as:

```
url: self.GET_GOAL_VIEW_URL,
```

Now in cases where the userEmail parameters would be passed explicitly, I need to use userEmail in the backend service code, but if the userEmail is absent in a call, I need to use another parameter, called userId, which is being added to the call by the proxy.

So I am not getting how to write the WS API so that it takes either this parameter or that, based on which one is used in the ajax request. Would be grateful for your assistance on this.

Comment: You need to develop the web service in such a way that it accepts both the parameters. The parameters can be optional and business processing logic will be based on which parameter is received in the request. Why don't you pass a `JSON` string containing all the possible parameters to the `REST` service and handle them in the service according to whatever has been passed in request.

Comment: Like @AniketV mentioned, you need to design your web service to accept both `userMail` and `userId`. What technology are you using to develop your backend web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameters as query params or body params.
You haven't mentioned which REST framework you will use on the backend so assuming you will use jersey the code should look as follows:

**With query parameters:**

```
@POST
@Path("/somepath")
public Response doSomething(@QueryParam("userEmail") String userEmail, @QueryParam("userId") String userId) {
    if(userEmail != null && !userEmail.equals("")) {
        //use email address
    } else if(userId != null && !userId.equals("")) {
        //use user id
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

**With body parameters:**

```
@POST
@Path("/somepath")
public Response doSomething(userDTO user) {
    if(user.getUserEmail() != null && !user.getUserEmail().equals("")) {
        //use email address
    } else if(user.getUserId() != null && !user.getUserId().equals("")) {
        //use user id
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

Of course you'll need to specify what content type you're returning, and change the method type if needed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I am using jersey and I am sending a query parameter request. So if I have 2 parameters in my REST API method as you have given above, and if I send only one parameter or no parameter at all in my ajax call, it would be fine, wont it be? It would see if any of these parameters are available in the ajax call, and accordingly match the parameter names in the request to the WS method parameters and set it.

Comment: @RohitGupta that is correct - JAX-RS (jersey) query parameters are not mandatory. In case your client side doesn't send them they will be null.